# How to correctly valid email unique agaist backend using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I read few articles about form validation and make nearly everything works.
Exepct one thing what's email validation for unique!.

**What I have:**

```
 // HTML with ng-pattern regex 
 <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
        ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/"
        placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="email" required>
```

after that somewhere below:

```
  // Here i try to check if email is valid, so if email was touched and  is 
  // invalid (regex failed)  OR controller return false on unique check
  <div class="custom-error" ng-show="ae.email.$dirty && (ae.email.$invalid || addCtrl.isEmailUnique(email))">
       <span ng-show="ae.email.$error.required">INVALID: Email is required</span>
       <span ng-show="ae.email.$error.pattern">INVALID: Email is not valid</span>
  </div>
```

**What's wrong:**

So to display error I added also this to HTML:

```
<span ng-show="!addCtrl.isEmailUnique(email)">INVALID: Email is already used</span>
```

- it's somehow doesnt display error even if error `isEmailUnique(email)` return `false`
- it also make milions of checks for it, what's terrible way how to make backend validation.

**What I want:**
Display error nicely if user email is not unique and really important thing, not request server for check email unique but just on change and only when email is not empty + is valid

---

EDIT:
Adding isEmailUnique method:

```
isEmailUnique: function(email) {
    UserService.isEmailUnique(email)
        .then(function (response) {
            addCtrl.uniqueEmail = response;
            return response
        }, function (error) {
            addCtrl.status = 'Unable to check validation';
        });
}
```

which basicly just call service which ask backend. I make check that service work correctly.

Comment: You'll need to post the code for `isEmailUnique`. Also, you'll want to "debounce" the calling of whatever service you're calling. Search for that keyword and you'll find plenty of articles on the net.

Comment: Have you try [angular-ui-validate](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate/master/demo/index.html)?

Comment: hi @miso thanks for answer, however it sound a bit like overkill for my single input validation to start using new thing. I create really small app with single form :)

Comment: Well, put the code of `isEmailUnique` in your question please. Are you returning a promise properly in that function?

Comment: Edited @miso, please if you have time check it